# Question regarding to the basis of L^p space via compact self adjoint operators. ( eg: inverse of -laplacian )

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Do eigenfunctions of inverse of elliptic operator (eg: Laplacian) form basis of $L^P(\Omega)$ ? For p=2 we know the answer is yes, I am looking for p>2. 
More generally, is it true that eigenfunctions of any compact on separable Banach Space form a basis for that?

Comment: What do you need this basis for?

Answer (score 0):

The operator which maps the function f(x) to $\int_0^x f(y)dy$ is compact, but it has no eigenfunctions. So the answer to your second question is no, even for Hilbert space. Also,
if we are not talking about orthonormal bases in Hilbert space, there are different notions of basis (Schauder, Riesz). The inverse of Laplacian in $L^p$ is rather well behaved, but you should not expect too many sweeping abstract generalizations.